# Will returning a creature trigger Prowess?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

**Pre-amble**
So I am currently building a Blue & White [Prowess](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Prowess) + [Heroic](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Heroic) deck in Standard. The idea that I can boost my heroic creatures with instants and auras and reap the benefit across all my prowess creatures.

**Possible combo**
I'm interested to know if the below combination will work. The [Lotus-Eye Mystics](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLotus-Eye%20Mystics%5d) would be in the graveyard, and then I would play Rally the Ancestors. In an ideal scenario the [Rally the Ancestors](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRally%20the%20Ancestors%5d) would trigger the Lotus-Eye Mystics Prowess because it's an instant. Then I can return an enchantment aura back to my hand also.

[image: Lotus Eye + Rally]

**Assumption**
I am assuming that Prowess has to be on the battlefield for the effect to trigger, which means that Rally the Ancestors would return the Lotus-Eye Mystics to the battlefield, but because they were in the graveyard when the instant was cast, the Prowess effect cannot trigger.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: To cast is to put on the stack, choose targets, and pay costs. It happens "long before" the spell resolves.

Comment: Glad to see you returned. If you want to tag a card in an answer or question, type `[mtg:Card Name]`. It will automatically create links to the Gatherer, just like this: [Rally the Ancestors](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391901). Also, when discussing a mechanic, you can assist answerers by linking to MTGSalvation's page on that mechanic. The syntax is easy: `[Prowess](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Prowess)`. Finally, you might be interested in seeing how U/W Heroic is holding up in [the big tournaments](http://www.starcitygames.com/pages/decklists/).

Comment: I know "proc" is a word for this too, but "trigger" (as in "triggered ability") is the Magic word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The creature with Prowess has to be on the battlefield to trigger it.**

Prowess is a triggered ability that only works while the card it's printed on is on the battlefield, i.e. as long as it's a permanent. Therefore, if you return Lotus-Eye Mystics with Rally the Ancestors, the Mystics will not get the Prowess trigger from that.

You will, however, get the enters-the-battlefield trigger from the Mystics.